# artifactory oss docker 5.0.0 upgraded to 5.1.0 now it won't start

Tags: docker, artifactory

I upgraded my docker compose file from 
  image: jfrog-docker-reg2.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:5.0.0 
to 
  image: jfrog-docker-reg2.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:5.1.0

I "down"'d the running 5.0.0. 
I docker-compose up -d...it pulled the new image. The container is running, but I see java errors. 
Tomcat reports that artifactory is down.

```
~/docker/artifactory$ docker-compose logs -t -f
Attaching to artifactory_artifactory_1
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:26.816388135Z
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:26.816472645Z Preparing to run Artifactory in Docker
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:26.816491957Z =====================================
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:26.935266533Z 2017-02-22 12:22:26   [42 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Checking open files and processes limits
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:26.948269905Z 2017-02-22 12:22:26   [45 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Current max open files is 1048576
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:26.961198250Z 2017-02-22 12:22:26   [57 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Current max open processes is unlimited
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:26.972750393Z 2017-02-22 12:22:26   [67 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Checking if /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory is mounted
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:27.132613278Z 2017-02-22 12:22:27   [72 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory is mounted
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:27.144238555Z 2017-02-22 12:22:27   [78 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Setting up data directories if missing
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:27.173774917Z 2017-02-22 12:22:27   [88 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Create artifactory user if missing
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:27.196929020Z 2017-02-22 12:22:27   [91 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] User does not exist. Creating it...
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:27.834005877Z 2017-02-22 12:22:27  [101 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Checking permissions on /opt/jfrog/artifactory
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:27.869833525Z 2017-02-22 12:22:27  [107 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] /opt/jfrog/artifactory is owned by root:root. Setting to artifactory:artifactory.
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:27.896618097Z 2017-02-22 12:22:27  [114 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Checking permissions on /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:27.912230901Z 2017-02-22 12:22:27  [120 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory is owned by root:root. Setting to artifactory:artifactory.
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:30.577407687Z 2017-02-22 12:22:30  [246 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] Checking DB_TYPE
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:30.579764945Z 2017-02-22 12:22:30  [291 entrypoint-artifactory.sh] DB_TYPE not set. Artifactory will use built in Derby DB
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:30.579779927Z
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:30.579782524Z =====================================
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:30.579784429Z
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:30.687525974Z Found java executable in JAVA_HOME (/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:33.186910701Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:33.186924479Z INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:33.225966854Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:33 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:33.225980723Z INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:33.227507698Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:33.227517178Z INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8019"]
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:33.228663981Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:33 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:33.228676761Z INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:33.232614970Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:33.232627764Z INFO: Starting service Catalina
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:33.232948961Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:33.232956147Z INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.39
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:33.241191149Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:33.241204841Z INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/artifactory.xml
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:35.298684059Z 2017-02-22 12:22:35 [ARTIFACTORY] [INFO] [Node ID: e547a11d7248c843:6a95f236:15a65c5ec3c:-8000] detected local modify for config 'db.properties'
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:35.299482570Z 2017-02-22 12:22:35 [ARTIFACTORY] [INFO] Start modify on local server='e547a11d7248c843:6a95f236:15a65c5ec3c:-8000' config='db.properties'
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:35.309042147Z 2017-02-22 12:22:35 [ARTIFACTORY] [INFO] Updating database with config changes for db.properties
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:35.359816960Z 2017-02-22 12:22:35 [ARTIFACTORY] [INFO] End modify on local server='e547a11d7248c843:6a95f236:15a65c5ec3c:-8000' config='db.properties'
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:35.362667271Z 2017-02-22 12:22:35 [ARTIFACTORY] [INFO] End modify on local server='e547a11d7248c843:6a95f236:15a65c5ec3c:-8000' config='artifactory.system.properties'
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:35.363038188Z 2017-02-22 12:22:35 [ARTIFACTORY] [INFO] Received file changed event but file is same as in the DB
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:35.364151155Z 2017-02-22 12:22:35 [ARTIFACTORY] [INFO] End modify on local server='e547a11d7248c843:6a95f236:15a65c5ec3c:-8000' config='artifactory.system.properties'
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:35.364460084Z 2017-02-22 12:22:35 [ARTIFACTORY] [INFO] Received file changed event but file is same as in the DB
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:35.365351799Z 2017-02-22 12:22:35 [ARTIFACTORY] [INFO] End create on local server='e547a11d7248c843:6a95f236:15a65c5ec3c:-8000' config='artifactory.mimeType'
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:35.365640415Z 2017-02-22 12:22:35 [ARTIFACTORY] [INFO] Received file changed event but file is same as in the DB
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:35.366264845Z 2017-02-22 12:22:35 [ARTIFACTORY] [INFO] End modify on local server='e547a11d7248c843:6a95f236:15a65c5ec3c:-8000' config='artifactory.mimeType'
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:35.366540789Z 2017-02-22 12:22:35 [ARTIFACTORY] [INFO] Received file changed event but file is same as in the DB
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:35.377610807Z 2017-02-22 12:22:35 [ARTIFACTORY] [INFO] End create on local server='e547a11d7248c843:6a95f236:15a65c5ec3c:-8000' config='artifactory.binarystore.xml'
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:35.377766328Z 2017-02-22 12:22:35 [ARTIFACTORY] [INFO] Received file changed event but file is same as in the DB
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:35.378495125Z 2017-02-22 12:22:35 [ARTIFACTORY] [INFO] End modify on local server='e547a11d7248c843:6a95f236:15a65c5ec3c:-8000' config='artifactory.binarystore.xml'
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:35.378622320Z 2017-02-22 12:22:35 [ARTIFACTORY] [INFO] Received file changed event but file is same as in the DB
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:35.630986369Z 2017-02-22 12:22:35 [ARTIFACTORY] [INFO] Starting Artifactory [artifactory.home=/opt/jfrog/artifactory].
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:35.688861387Z 2017-02-22 12:22:35,686 [localhost-startStop-1] [INFO ] (o.j.a.s.v.c.EnvironmentConversionRunner:65) - Running environment pre bootstrap conversion for version 1.0.0
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:35.866738433Z 2017-02-22 12:22:35,866 [localhost-startStop-1] [INFO ] (o.j.a.s.AccessApplicationContext:23) - Refreshing org.jfrog.access.server.AccessApplicationContext@6ad78207: startup date [Wed Feb 22 12:22:35 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.060074316Z 2017-02-22 12:22:36,059 [localhost-startStop-1] [INFO ] (o.j.a.s.d.u.AccessJdbcHelper:72) - Database: Apache Derby 10.11.1.1 - (1616546). Driver: Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver 10.11.1.1 - (1616546)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.060237383Z 2017-02-22 12:22:36,060 [localhost-startStop-1] [INFO ] (o.j.a.s.d.u.AccessJdbcHelper:74) - Connection URL: jdbc:derby:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data/derby
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.191718201Z 2017-02-22 12:22:36,191 [localhost-startStop-1] [INFO ] (o.j.a.s.s.TokenServiceImpl:72) - Scheduling task for revoking expired tokens using cron expression: 0 0 0/1 * * ?
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.198395456Z 2017-02-22 12:22:36,198 [localhost-startStop-1] [INFO ] (o.j.a.s.AccessServerBootstrap:284) - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Generating private key and root certificate
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.655397526Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.655414789Z SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.656507071Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.656520536Z SEVERE: Context [/artifactory] startup failed due to previous errors
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.675952045Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:36 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.675967719Z WARNING: The web application [artifactory] registered the JDBC driver [org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.676728811Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:36 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.676742404Z WARNING: The web application [artifactory] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.676746716Z  sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService.poll(Native Method)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.676749759Z  sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService.access$600(LinuxWatchService.java:47)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.676752567Z  sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService$Poller.run(LinuxWatchService.java:314)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.676755422Z  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.677275753Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:36 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.677284451Z WARNING: The web application [artifactory] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.677286953Z  sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.677293805Z  java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.677297216Z  java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.677300109Z  java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:492)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.677302745Z  java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.take(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:680)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.677305264Z  sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchService.take(AbstractWatchService.java:118)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.677307876Z  org.artifactory.common.config.watch.FileWatchingManager.doWatch(FileWatchingManager.java:68)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.677310402Z  org.artifactory.common.config.watch.FileWatchingManager$$Lambda$2/1083544293.run(Unknown Source)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.677313264Z  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.677846322Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:36 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.677856562Z WARNING: The web application [artifactory] appears to have started a thread named [Tomcat JDBC Pool Cleaner[1752596955:1487766156050]] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.677859363Z  java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.677861213Z  java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.677863029Z  java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.678387941Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:36 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.678398170Z WARNING: The web application [artifactory] appears to have started a thread named [jf-access-task1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.678401170Z  sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.678403067Z  java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.678404883Z  java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.678406789Z  java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.678408624Z  java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.678410489Z  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.678412289Z  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.678414046Z  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.678415820Z  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.679014126Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:36 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.679023908Z SEVERE: The web application [artifactory] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@57e78e7c]) and a value of type [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager] (value [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager@ee8b1e6]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.679338364Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:36 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.679347682Z SEVERE: The web application [artifactory] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@57e78e7c]) and a value of type [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager] (value [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager@5762d6d6]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.679672676Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:36 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.679681061Z SEVERE: The web application [artifactory] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@57e78e7c]) and a value of type [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager] (value [org.apache.derby.iapi.services.context.ContextManager@7efa140]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.684570312Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.684588424Z INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/artifactory.xml has finished in 3,443 ms
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.685074980Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.685085480Z INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.703022976Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.703036857Z INFO: Deployment of web application directory /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 18 ms
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.704487040Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.704502536Z INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.707151141Z Feb 22, 2017 12:22:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
artifactory_1  | 2017-02-22T12:22:36.707166840Z INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8019"]
```

My compose file:

```
~/docker/artifactory$ cat docker-compose.yml
artifactory:
  image: jfrog-docker-reg2.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:5.1.0
  ports:
    - "8083:8081"
  volumes:
    - /mnt/Drive2/artifactory_docker/backup:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/backup
    - /mnt/Drive2/artifactory_docker/logs:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/logs
    - /mnt/Drive2/artifactory_docker/data:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data
  restart: always
```

Going to the artifactory URL gives me:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /artifactory

type Status report

message /artifactory

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.39
```

Answer (score 2):

The Deployment process changed. You should adjust your volume mounts.

[Installing Artifactory with Docker](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+with+Docker)

/E: If you need to get your old version running, try to retrieve the lost files from your old docker volumes. You need to find your missing `access` folder containing private keys. This may be helpful:

```
$ docker volumes ls
$ docker inspect <id> # search for Mountpoint ->
$ ls -lah /var/lib/docker/volumes/e1735eadb76e4b2a0cdf6e6808f0f083272acaf87d635c517c482771e5291fff/_data/
```